# Argument of type 'RegExp' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to import an Excel File like so:

```js
onFileChange(event: any) 
  {
    const inputFile: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(event.target); 
    const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (event: any) => 
    {
      const binaryString: string = event.target.result;
      const workBook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(binaryString, { type: 'binary', sheetStubs: true}); 
      /* sheetstubs true supposedly shows empty cells but isn't */
      console.log(typeof binaryString)

      const workSheetName: string = workBook.SheetNames[0];
      console.log(workSheetName)
      const workSheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = workBook.Sheets[workSheetName];

      this.data = <Array>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet, 
      {header: 1, blankrows: true }));


    };
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(inputFile.files[0]);

  }
```

and want to find the index (basically the column number) of any cell that contains the phrase 'cap' in it using regex.

I am trying to use regex like so below to search for the term `cap` in any of the cell but am met with the following error,

`Argument of type 'RegExp' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.` I am unclear as to what this error is trying to indicate to me and what might be a good way to achieve what I am trying to achieve.

```js
getManufacturerDescriptionColumn()
  {
    for (const row in this.data)
    {
      var descIndex = row.indexOf(/cap*/i)
      return descIndex
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`String.indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#Syntax) expects a `string` as it's first parameter.

The `/<pattern>/` syntax is a regular expression literal and it results in the instantiation of a `RegExp` object. So, as the error message indicates, it is not a `string`.

To fix this, you should use a string instead of regular expression when you call `String.indexOf()`:

```
row.indexOf('cap')
```

This search is not case-insensitive though. If you want case insensitivity, then using a regular expression would be prudent.

To use a regular expression, what you want is the [`String.search()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search#Syntax). It expects a `RegExp` as it's first parameter and has an equivalent return value (i.e. the index within the string of where the first match begins).

---

A couple more observations:

- The way your loop is written, it will return the result of the first iteration even if no match is found.
- The regular expression you specified (`/cap*/i`) is looking for the characters `ca` followed by 0 or more `p` characters. So it will match `ca`, `cap`, `capppp`, etc.

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
getManufacturerDescriptionColumn() {
  for (const row in this.data) {
    let matchIndex = row.search(/cap/i);
    if (matchIndex > -1) {
      return matchIndex;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hmmmm so this resolves the error but gives me undefined even though I can see for a fact that the value is in the table and also good catch on the loop there I had not thought of that the explanation was very helpful though

Comment: thank you, I thought the `*` character was indicate that it can look for anything afterwards? nonetheless though when I call console.log(matchIndex) I am getting undefined

Comment: `*` is quantifier that applies the preceding item (`p` in this case). What you're thinking of is `.*`, where `.` means "any character" (except line terminators) and the addition of the `*` quantifier means "any character 0 or more times". See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Quantifiers#Types) for reference.

Comment: If you're still having problems finding a match, you may to troubleshoot by logging the value of `row` before performing the test, just to confirm that you're actually testing the strings you're intending to. For example, if you haven't fixed the looping logic, then you're not going to be testing anything other than the first element of `this.data`.

Comment: yeah the looping is probably throwing me for a loop (no pun intended) in this case because this.data is an object of arrays where each array in the object is a row in the excel file, and each item is indicative of a cell, so I'm figuring just the 1 for-loop with added conditional should've worked, I don't think I need to add another layer of iteration but I'll keep trouble shooting to see what's up